# Rcpp lapply() or mapply() with 5 arguments

Tags: r, rcpp

I have two functions that are conceptually like the two below. The first one builds a model with a set of parameters. The second one builds all models with 4 parameters held constant and one supplied in a list.

```
build_one_model <- function(a, b, x, c, d) {
  a + b + x + c + d
}
build_all_models <- function(a, b, xList, c, d) {
  lapply(xList, function(x) build_one_model(a, b, x, c, d))
}
```

Example usage:

```
xList <- list(1, 2, 3)
build_all_models(1, 2, xList, 4, 5)
```

```
[[1]]
[1] 13

[[2]]
[1] 14

[[3]]
[1] 15
```

Now I can convert `build_one_model()` to `Rcpp`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
double build_one_model(double a, double b, double x, double c, double d) {
  return a + b + x + c + d;
}
```

But how can I convert `build_all_models()`? `lapply()` only takes one input, and `mapply()` takes up to three, but I have 5.

Comment: No need to convert `build_all_models` at all.

Comment: I need to, because I want to speed it up. These functions are in a package, and outside the package I need to call `build_all_models()` multiple times at various values for the other parameters.

Comment: I reckon I can write a `for` loop in `build_all_models()`. I'm in C++ after all, where `for` loops are not penalized like in R.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Hmm... Maybe you're right, converting `build_all_models()` to Rcpp does not speed it up. The toy function does speed up about 20 times, though, from ~1700 ms to ~60 ms. I guess it's the absolute difference, not relative one, that counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can settle with a `for` loop. I have to remind myself that I'm in C++ and not R, so `for` loops are not bad.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
double build_one_model(double a, double b, double x, double c, double d) {
  return a + b + x + c + d;
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
List build_all_models(double a, double b, List xList, double c, double d) {

  Rcpp::List ans(xList.length());
  for (int i = 0; i < xList.length(); i++) {
    ans[i] = build_one_model(a, b, xList[i], c, d);  
  }
  return ans;
}
```

```
xList <- list(1, 2, 3)
build_all_models(1, 2, xList, 4, 5)
```

```
[[1]]
[1] 13

[[2]]
[1] 14

[[3]]
[1] 15
```